# python - transpose rows to columns, and calculate new column value as sum of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'channels' : ['EMAIL','FAX','MAIL','PHONE','Marketing','SMS','VISIT','Profiling','Approved_Email','EMAIL','FAX','MAIL','PHONE','Marketing','SMS','VISIT','Profiling','Approved_Email_vod'],
                   'ID' : [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006],
                   'INTR_COUNT' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'PERSONA' : ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']})
```

What i want to do is define a function that will take a df such as the above and create new columns based on the unique categories in 'channels'.

| ID | EMAIL | FAX | MAIL | PHONE | SMS | VISIT | Marketing | Approved_email | Persona |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | A |

And so on for the rest of the IDs

I've written this function so far:

```
def channel_pivot(df: pd.DataFrame):
    #where df is the df stated above
    x = df
    #subsetting to pivot only on focus cols
    y = df[['channels', 'INTR', 'HCP']] 
    #pivot operation
    y = set_index('ID')
    y1 = y.pivot(columns='channels', values = sum('INTR')).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
    df1 = y1.merge(x, left_index=True, right_on='ID')
    return df1
```

I can't get the sum function to work inside the pivot function though, so how can I sum up the count of interactions for a given ID for each channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` with `.agg()`:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby(["ID", "channels"])
    .agg({"INTR_COUNT": "sum", "PERSONA": "first"})
    .set_index("PERSONA", append=True)
    .unstack(level=1)
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
)
x.columns.name = None
print(x)
```

Prints:

|  | ID | PERSONA | Approved_Email | Approved_Email_vod | EMAIL | FAX | MAIL | Marketing | PHONE | Profiling | SMS | VISIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1001 | A | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1002 | B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1003 | C | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1004 | A | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 4 | 1005 | B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1006 | C | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: thank you my guy! this worked, I certified it